# Blur ImageView to Show additional Details. Swift

Tags: swift, uiview

Imagine you have to redesign current instagram feed, with requirement - images should be border to border -> so user doesn't see any additional information e.g. - usernames, likes, comments, etc. No white space. 
When user long presses the image, that image blurs and all additional info appears. User should be able to click on newly appeared elements. 
What are my options for such UX implementation?

Answer (score 0):

This question is too vague, but you can just add a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to the `UIImageView` containing each image. When that's triggered, you can set the alpha value so the image is transparent and also add your blur effect here. The username/likes/other info would then become visible and clickable from behind the image. Might set the whole thing up in a `UITableView` so that you can scroll through all the images that are loaded.